# my jquery slider doesn't show value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have made this slider which should show the value at the end, but the value doesn't change when i slide the slider... In the console I get the error slider is not defined.

```js
$("#ex6").slider();
$("#ex6").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer"> 
   <input type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="ex6"> <br>
   <span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it may be easier to add all the labels/values dynamically with JQuery in an implementation something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/william/RSkpH/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got confused about Image Slider and Range Slider. On Image slider only you can catch the event `.on('slide'`. In Range slide you have to use like `.on('input'` and assign the current slider value like below. Also no need of using `$('#ex6').slider()`.

```js
$('#ex6').on('input', function(){
    $('#ex6SliderVal').html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div class="slidecontainer"> 
   <input type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="ex6"> <br>
   <span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal"></span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you feel this is the correct answer then mark it as an answer.

Comment: Note that if you want to use jQuery slider, you should keep the `$('#ex6').slider()` line.

Answer (score 0):

The slider doesn't trigger the slide event in your case, you can use the input event though:

```js
$(".slider").slider();
$("#ex6").on("input", function() {
    $("#ex6SliderVal").text(this.value);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="slidecontainer"> 
   <input type="range" min="1" max="6" value="1" class="slider" id="ex6"> <br>
   <span id="ex6CurrentSliderValLabel">Current Slider Value: <span id="ex6SliderVal"></span></span>
</div>
```

---

Also, Slider is not a component of the basic jQuery library, you'll need to add jQueryUI to your project. You can download it [here](http://jqueryui.com/download). Be careful to add it **after** jQuery. Also make sure you have a CSS theme.

Comment: but it still doesn`t show the value at the end, and my console doesn`t show any errors either

Comment: This doesn`t work either var slider = new Slider("#ex6");
slider.on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
 $("#ex6SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
});

Comment: Did you add jQueryUI library to your project?

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  yes

Comment: Check my last edit to import it correctly. I tried with your tag and got errors.

Comment: Well, just edited with a working snippet but too late. Too bad.